# How can i find - which portlets are deployed on which pages in Liferay 6.1?

Tags: liferay

In other words, Which Database tables do i need to look into for the mapping of a portlet to a page in an organization? If there is such a thing?! We are using Liferay 6.1.20

Comment: layoutset is the table you are looking for. Moreover there is one app available in liferay marketplace.(portlet location tracker)

Comment: and also Layout table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apart from the [marketplace portlet](http://www.liferay.com/it/marketplace/-/mp/application/27156990).

If you have access to the Database you can fire a simple query on the `Layout` table to know in what all pages your portlet is added:

```
SELECT * FROM Layout WHERE typeSettings LIKE '%my_WAR_myportlet%';
```

Also you can build a FinderImpl with service-builder to execute this query through a portlet and add that portlet to page to display in whatever format you want.

---

Below is another solution without deploying any portlet and without having access to the DB (tested on MySQL DB):

1. Go to Server Administration
2. Go to Script tab
3. Select `Beanshell` from the Language drop-down
4. Paste the following script code in the textarea and press the button execute:

   ```
   import com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.jdbc.DataAccess;
   import com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.Log;
   import com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.LogFactoryUtil;
   import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.StringBundler;

   import java.sql.Connection;
   import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
   import java.sql.ResultSet;
   import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;

   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.Collections;
   import java.util.Iterator;
   import java.util.List;

   Connection con = null;
   PreparedStatement ps = null;
   ResultSet rs = null;

   try {
       con = DataAccess.getUpgradeOptimizedConnection();

       // your custom query here
       String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Layout WHERE typeSettings LIKE '%my_WAR_myportlet%'";

       out.println("SQL Query: "+ sqlQuery);

       ps = con.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);

       rs = ps.executeQuery();

       ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

       int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

       List rows = new ArrayList();

       List columnLabels = new ArrayList();

       columnLabels.add("Sr. No.");

       for (int c = 1; c <= columnCount; c++) {
           String cl = rsmd.getColumnLabel(c);
           columnLabels.add(cl);
       }

       while (rs.next()) {
           List row = new ArrayList(columnCount);

           for (int c = 1; c <= columnCount; c++) {
               Object value = rs.getObject(c);
               row.add(value);
           }

           rows.add(row);
       }

       // --- formatting the results ---

       out.append("<div class=\"lfr-search-container \"><div class=\"results-grid\">");
       out.append("<table class=\"taglib-search-iterator\">");
       out.append("<thead>");
       out.append("<tr class=\"portlet-section-header results-header\">");

       for (String value : columnLabels) {
           out.append("<th>");
           out.append(value);
           out.append("</th>");
       }

       out.append("</tr>");
       out.append("</thead>");
       out.append("<tbody>");

       boolean alt = false;

       long resultsCount = 1;

       for (List line : rows) {
           out.append("<tr class=\"portlet-section-alternate results-row " + (alt ? "alt" : "") + "\">");

           // for sr. no.
           out.append("<td>");
           out.append(resultsCount + "");
           out.append("</td>");

           resultsCount = resultsCount + 1;

           for (Iterator iterator = line.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
               Object value = (Object) iterator.next();
               out.append("<td>");
               if (value != null) {
                   out.append(value.toString());
               } else {
                   out.append("<span style=\"font-style:italic\">null</span>");
               }
               out.append("</td>");
           }
           out.append("</tr>");
           alt = !alt;
       }

       out.append("</tbody>");

       out.append("</table>");
       out.append("</div></div>");

   } catch (Exception exp) {
       out.println("ERROR: " + exp);
       throw exp;
   }
   finally {
       DataAccess.cleanUp(con, ps, rs);
   }
   ```
5. ***Please remember to change the string `my_WAR_myportlet` to your portletId***
6. Needless to say you can modify the script to update the styles and can show selective columns. Also you can run any SQL query, just update `String sqlQuery`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works like a charm and It's really cool! Had never been in Script Tab of Control Panel. Now i now one use of it. Still Learning Liferay. Thanks for your help!

Comment: :-) My pleasure. But in stackoverflow there is a different way to say thank-you ... hope you know what I mean ;-) ... hehe

Comment: I realize that But I don't have the 'resources' to thank you yet :(

Comment: I think still you can accept this as an answer if it solves your question

Comment: Great answer, I only edited it, so the answer is MySQL-independent (waiting for peer review). Because of the specific "LIMIT" clause, one can get a nothing-saying error `"[EditServerAction:523] ... Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.jdbc.DataAccess; import com.liferay.portal. . . . '' : TargetError"` in the logs (an example of incorrect exception handling, Liferay authors) when using other databases.

Comment: Plus one usually wants to know the *URLs* of the portlet's pages. Here is a sample query to do this (tested against Liferay 6.2 database):

  `SELECT site.friendlyurl || (case when page.privatelayout then '/group' else '/web' end) || page.friendlyurl as pageUrl
  FROM layout page
  JOIN group_ site ON site.groupid = page.groupid
  WHERE page.typeSettings LIKE '%my_WAR_myportlet%';`

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution, a free marketplace plugin that resolve your issue.

http://www.liferay.com/it/marketplace/-/mp/application/27156990

Comment: Thanks for a easy solution! Can't vote it up yet, will do when i have some reputation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code to get all the portlets from the first column

```
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
Layout layout = themeDisplay.getLayout();
LayoutTypePortlet layoutTypePortlet = (LayoutTypePortlet) layout.getLayoutType();
List<Portlet> portlets = layoutTypePortlet.getAllPortlets("column-1");
for (Portlet portlet : portlets) {
    // print your portlet.getPortletId() or do whatever you need
}
```

Comment: or just call layoutTypePortlet.getAllPortlets() to get all portlets on a page

Answer (score 0):

[layout] is the table in which you can find out which portlets(typeSettings ) are deployed on which page