# Creating Roles Programmatically for each User Group

Tags: java, liferay

I want to create a Role for each User Group within my portal so that I can grant specific access to many users at once, depending on what groups they belong to.

Using Liferay API, is there any way to programmatically add a Role for each User Group that exists within the Portal?

This would be more efficient than adding each role individually through the UI.

Something like

```
for(i = 0; i < userGroups.size(); i++){
    roles.add(userGroups[i].getName());
}
```

If possible, I'd like to then assign the same User Group to that Role within the same method, otherwise the role would know nothing of the associated user group:

```
roles.assignUserGroup(userGroups[i]);
```

Anyone accomplished a task similar to this?

Linked Liferay Forum Post  http://liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/46355079

Comment: You can create only below types or roles in Liferay: 
1) Regular role: Permissions are defined at the portal level and are applied at the portal level, 2) Site role: Permissions are defined at the portal level and are applied to one specific site, 3)
 Organization role: Permissions are defined at the portal level and are applied to one specific organization, 4) Team: Permissions are defined within a specific site and are assigned within that specific site.
It doesn't support Roles at User-group level. Please describe your requirement so that I can suggest an alternate way to achieve it.

Comment: You can indeed assign a Role to a User Group. It will be one of the 4 roles you've mentioned but users belonging to a group can still inherit a common role. I'm restricting the view access to certain user groups for certain pages, assigning roles to user groups gives grants this ability and many more if needed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short you need to create a Role with a similar name as that of the UserGroups you have and then assign the UserGroup to that Role.

You can do that programmatically with Liferay's API, since that is how liferay also creates the different types of Roles and assigns users, user-groups etc to the role.

You just need to dig into to the source code to do this. Check source code for [`RoleLocalServiceImpl`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/service/impl/RoleLocalServiceImpl.java), [`UserGroupLocalServiceImpl`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/service/impl/UserGroupLocalServiceImpl.java) and [`GroupLocalServiceImpl`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/service/impl/GroupLocalServiceImpl.java).

I am providing the steps for **Liferay v6.2**, there should not be much change in 6.0 and 6.1:

1. Fetch all the UserGroups using [UserGroupLocalServiceUtil.getUserGroups(companyId)](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/service/impl/UserGroupLocalServiceImpl.java#L448)
2. Loop through it as you have done:

   ```
   for (UserGroup userGroup : userGroups) {
      ... // steps to follow
   }
   ```
3. Get the name of the UserGroup: `userGroup.getName()`
4. Create a Role using [RoleLocalServiceUtil.addRole( ... )](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/service/impl/RoleLocalServiceImpl.java#L186) and assign the userGroup to role using [GroupLocalServiceUtil.addRoleGroups( ... )](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/service/impl/GroupLocalServiceImpl.java#L549)

   ```
   for (UserGroup userGroup : userGroups) {
       String userGroupName = userGroup.getName();
       // for locale specific title (optional, can be null)
       Map<Locale, String> titleMap = new HashMap<Locale, String>();
       titleMap.put(Locale.ENGLISH, userGroupName);

       // for locale specific description (optional, can be null)
       Map<Locale, String> descriptionMap = new HashMap<Locale, String>();
       titleMap.put(Locale.ENGLISH, "Role created for UserGroup - " + userGroupName);

       int type = RoleConstants.TYPE_REGULAR;

       // adding the role
       Role role = RoleLocalServiceUtil.addRole(userId, Role.class.getName(), 0, userGroupName, titleMap, descriptionMap, type, null, null);

       // assigning the UserGroup to the role
       GroupLocalServiceUtil.addRoleGroups(role.getRoleId(), new long[]{userGroup.getGroupId()}); // need to pass groupId and not userGroupId
   }
   ```
5. Now were would you write this code-snippet? There are various places depending upon what requirement you have:

   1. Custom plugin portlet with a UI to execute this code. (better if required periodically)
   2. Custom plugin action-hook and the code goes inside a StartUpAction, executes the code when the hook is being deployed. Hook should be undeployed or else will run everytime the hook is deployed. (better for one time use)
   3. Custom plugin upgrade hook, executes the code during deployment once based on the upgrade condition. (better for one time use)
   4. Use Beanshell, <kbd>Server Administration</kbd> → <kbd>Script</kbd> → <kbd>Select Beanshell</kbd> → <kbd>Paste the code-snippet</kbd> → <kbd>Execute</kbd>. You need to have the proper import statements and then just the code-snippet and you are good to go. For an example of Beanshell usage you can check [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26231042/468763). (better for one time use)

Even after all this you would still have to take the pains to give permission to each role ;-)

Hope this helps though.

Comment: Just so that other users know please include the link to your Liferay post as well in the question and vice-versa in the liferay forum. This helps the community to know whether it is answered somewhere or not. Will save valuable time of the community. Thanks. https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/46355079

Comment: @PrakashK  Thank you so much for  "need to pass groupId and not userGroupId" this comment