# Liferay : How to see which portlets are composing a page?

Tags: liferay

I'm new to liferay.

I imported a big lar into my liferay instance but, for the moment, have none of the required portlets : there are a lot of portlets in the project I'm joining.

Currently, I have the site structure, but the pages display the message that the portlet is not here (logical).
For comprehension purposes, I wanted to build my portlets one after the other, on the need, to see them appear by the grace of liferay ;-)
But for that I wanted to know **which** portlet is missing.

This thread : [How can i find - which portlets are deployed on which pages in Liferay 6.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185039/how-can-i-find-which-portlets-are-deployed-on-which-pages-in-liferay-6-1) explain how to achieve this through the DB.

Is there really no built-in solution to do it through the liferay interface? Have we really to hack in the DB to get the info or install plugin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your browser console, `Liferay.Portlet.list` contains all portlets in the page.
This value is generated by `themeDisplay.getLayoutTypePortlet().getAllPortlets()` on the server.

Comment: Thx, I'll try that asap.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can also look at the HTML code of the page and look for elements with the class `portlet-boundary`. For example this belongs to an instance of the Journal Content Portlet (Portlet name 56):

```
<div class="portlet-boundary portlet-boundary_56_ portlet-static portlet-static-end portlet-borderless portlet-journal-content full-screen" id="p_p_id_56_INSTANCE_WdRdMGe86kDa_">
```

Comment: Thank you. 

I am very impressed that there is no clean built-in features allowing to get this information.